# Unexplainable Load Average CentOS Linux php-fpm

Tags: linux, centos, php

we have a strange problem with "Load average" on server, we tried to solve the problem but no luck and now we trying to find help.

We have a VPS CentOS Linux 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5 x86_64 GNU/Linux with 2 physical cores, 2GB RAM, this server is just running php-fpm 5.3.10 no other services running on it.

php using Redis via TCP (~1000 request per second), Redis server can easily make 60000 request per second and have a LA of 0.01.

Symptoms:

Random spikes of LA from 16 to 40 with no obvious reason. In spite of this fact CPU usage is ~40%, ~10% of system and memory usage is less then half.

```
Cpu0  : 36.7%us, 11.9%sy,  0.0%ni, 44.2%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  7.2%si,  0.0%st
Cpu1  : 39.8%us, 10.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 26.2%id,  0.0%wa, 10.0%hi, 14.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   2058776k total,  1241500k used,   817276k free,   160172k buffers
Swap:  1048568k total,        0k used,  1048568k free,   876888k cached
```

Spikes are not related to network activity or cron jobs.
Amount of requests to php per seconds is ~70.

PHP slow log shows us, that a lot of scripts not getting they turn to run even after 5 seconds! 
php Slow log (5s):

```
[pool www] pid 7016
script_filename = /var/www/myapp/index.php
[0x000000001820d230] session_start() /var/www/myapp/index.php:10
```

10 first lines of index.php:

```
<?php
$starttime=microtime(TRUE);
srand();

ob_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

session_start();
```

Sessions located at memory partition... no problems with IO.

config php-fpm:

```
listen.backlog = 18192
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 256
pm.start_servers = 48
pm.min_spare_servers = 16
pm.max_spare_servers = 64
pm.max_requests = 512
```

Please if some one have any suggestions how to lower LA, and delays.

Answer (score 1):

Load average is a measure of the number of processes you have in your run queue at any given time. It is not, per se, a measure of how overloaded your machine is, and it may not be a problem for your load average to spike at times -- it does not necessarily mean the machine is overloaded.

Without additional information about why you believe the load average to be a problem and the sort of load conditions the machine is experiencing, it is difficult to answer in more detail.

Comment: Normally execution of scripts takes about 100ms max, but when LA is spiking execution of scripts take 5second or even more.

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27M Mar  1 05:11 /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log 
Like we see slow low is 27Mb from one week, thats not a normal condition.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with load average, it is "why does this script suddenly take so long to execute". What have you done to try to debug that question?

Comment: We tried strace, apd on development clone server, we switched from php-fpm to Apache, we debugged script and found nothing. What I'm trying to say that i have no idea where to look. 
All slow log's end's with socket_write, socket_read or session_start.
Can it be that something wrong with TCP/IP configuration?

Comment: I would strongly doubt that the TCP configuration is the problem.

Comment: Redis is sending a lot of small packages 1 to 10 bytes, any suggestion how to configure the system?

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP config is high for your 2GB ram, try to decrease start_servers
Check this config [Install PHP 5.3.10 with PHP-FPM on CentOS 6.2](http://gadelkareem.com/2012/02/29/install-php-5-3-10-with-php-fpm-on-centos-6-2-64-bit/)